# preventing active record attributes from being modified by forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Ruby on Rails, it's very easy to update a model from an HTML form. Usually you can just create a form_for with the model, and the fields in there will be updated when the user hits the submit button.

Say though that a malicious user wants to update their 'salary' without going through the proper channels. couldn't they just inject a field by the name of 'salary' when updating their email address (for example) and set their pay to basically be whatever they want? how do i specify which fields can be modified and which can't to prevent this?

Seeing things like

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

seems scary. They could update anything. I understand the use of attr_accessible, but that's only relevant for mass updates, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict what fields can be mass assigned using:

```
attr_accessible :name, :address # no :salary
```

Comment: right, but couldn't the user just post the one :salary field instead of everything? or does update_attributes always follow attr_accessible?

Comment: `attr_accessible` lists the fields that are allowed to be mass-assigned, such as using `update_attributes`.  They can't assign the value because of that.